# Is there a way to apply the theme to diffrent Item of the navigation view?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-navigationview

I am apply style on navigation view using below code

```
app:theme="@style/NavigationItemTheme" //NavigationItemTheme is my style.
```

it apply same theme to all navigation items. I want to apply different theme to different items. How will achieve please help.

Is it possible to apply different theme to different items in navigation view?.

Answer (score 0):

you can add children to your navigation view and add style to children

```
 <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>
 </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

Comment: you should add styles to linearlayouts for example